# C# Winforms Connect Four: How to Check if a column is full?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

So I am a complete beginner at C#, and I have been using a Tic Tac Toe tutorial by 'csharpdemos' to try and develop a Connect four game. As of now, the game can be played, apart from one problem. I have an int movesmade, which keeps track of the moves made by the users, so it can determine who's turn it is next. However, when a column is filled, movesmade will still increase by one when a user clicks the column, although no values are set. This means that the turns will be out of sync. I will show my code below.

```
public class Board
{
    public int movesMade = 0;


    private Holder[,] holders = new Holder[5, 5];

    public const int CT1 = 0;
    public const int CT2 = 1;
    public const int B = 2;

    public void startBoard()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
            {

                holders[x, y] = new Holder();
                holders[x, y].setValue(B);
                holders[x, y].setLocation(new Point(x, y));

            }
        }
    }

    public void detectHit(Point location)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        if ((location.X < 100) )
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 4;

            if (holders[0, 4].getValue() == CT1 || holders[0, 4].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 3;
            if (holders[0, 3].getValue() == CT1 || holders[0, 3].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 2;
            if (holders[0, 2].getValue() == CT1 || holders[0, 2].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 1;
            if (holders[0, 1].getValue() == CT1 || holders[0, 1].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 0;









        }
        else if (location.X > 100 && location.X < 200)
        {
            x = 1;
            y = 4;

            if (holders[1, 4].getValue() == CT1 || holders[1, 4].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 3;
            if (holders[1, 3].getValue() == CT1 || holders[1, 3].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 2;
            if (holders[1, 2].getValue() == CT1 || holders[1, 2].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 1;
            if (holders[1, 1].getValue() == CT1 || holders[1, 1].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 0;



        }
        else if (location.X > 200 && location.X < 300 )
        {
            x = 2;
            y = 4;

            if (holders[2, 4].getValue() == CT1 || holders[2, 4].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 3;
            if (holders[2, 3].getValue() == CT1 || holders[2, 3].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 2;
            if (holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT1 || holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 1;
            if (holders[2, 1].getValue() == CT1 || holders[2, 1].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 0;



        }
        else if (location.X > 300 && location.X < 400)
        {
            x = 3;
            y = 4;

            if (holders[3, 4].getValue() == CT1 || holders[3, 4].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 3;
            if (holders[3, 3].getValue() == CT1 || holders[3, 3].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 2;
            if (holders[3, 2].getValue() == CT1 || holders[3, 2].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 1;
            if (holders[3, 1].getValue() == CT1 || holders[3, 1].getValue() == CT2)
                y = 0;



        }
        else if (location.X > 400 )
        {
            x = 4;
            y = 4;

                if (holders[4, 4].getValue() == CT1 || holders[4, 4].getValue() == CT2)
                    y = 3;
                if (holders[4, 3].getValue() == CT1 || holders[4, 3].getValue() == CT2)
                    y = 2;
                if (holders[4, 2].getValue() == CT1 || holders[4, 2].getValue() == CT2)
                    y = 1;
                if (holders[4, 1].getValue() == CT1 || holders[4, 1].getValue() == CT2)
                    y = 0;






        }


        movesMade++;


        if (holders[x, 0].getValue() == CT2)
        { 
            movesMade = 1;
            movesMade++;
        }

        if (holders[x, 0].getValue() == CT1)
        {
            movesMade = 0;
            movesMade++;
        }




        if (movesMade % 2 == 0)
        {


            if (holders[x, 0].getValue() == 2)
            {
                Drawing.drawCt1(new Point(x, y));
                holders[x, y].setValue(CT1);
                Drawing.drawCt2(new Point(x, y));
                holders[x, y].setValue(CT2);        
            }
            if (holders[0,y].getValue() == 1 || holders[0,y].getValue() == 0)




            if (detectColumn())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WINNER!");
            }
            if (detectRow())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WINNER!");
            }
            if (detectDiagonal())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WINNER!");
            }
        }
        else
        {


                if (holders[x, 0].getValue() == 2)
                {

                    Drawing.drawCt2(new Point(x, y));
                    holders[x, y].setValue(CT2);
                    Drawing.drawCt1(new Point(x, y));
                    holders[x, y].setValue(CT1);


                }





                if (detectColumn())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("WINNER!");
                }
                if (detectRow())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("WINNER!");
                }
                if (detectDiagonal())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("WINNER!");
                }
        }


    }

    public bool detectColumn()
    {
        bool isWon = false;

        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {

                    if ((holders[x, 0].getValue() == CT1 && holders[x, 1].getValue() == CT1 && holders[x, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[x, 3].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[x, 1].getValue() == CT1 && holders[x, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[x, 3].getValue() == CT1 && holders[x, 4].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[x, 0].getValue() == CT2 && holders[x, 1].getValue() == CT2 && holders[x, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[x, 3].getValue() == CT2) || (holders[x, 1].getValue() == CT2 && holders[x, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[x, 3].getValue() == CT2 && holders[x, 4].getValue() == CT2))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }


        }
        return isWon;
    }

    public bool detectRow()
    {
        bool isWon = false;

        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            switch (y)
            {
                case 0:
                    if ((holders[0, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[0, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT2))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if ((holders[0, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[0, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT2))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if ((holders[0, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[0, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT2))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if ((holders[0, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[0, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT2))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if ((holders[0, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT1 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[0, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2) || (holders[1, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, y].getValue() == CT2 && holders[4, y].getValue() == CT2))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;




            }


        }
        return isWon;
    }

    public bool detectDiagonal()
    {
        bool isWon = false;

        //If statements for checking if counters are in diagonal.There are only 8 total possible diagonal wins therefore 8 if statments

        //Diagonal from [0,0] to [3,3] for each counter
        if ((holders[0, 0].getValue() == CT1 && holders[1, 1].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, 3].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[0, 0].getValue() == CT2 && holders[1, 1].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, 3].getValue() == CT2))
        {
            isWon = true;
        }
        //Diagonal from [0,1] to [3,4] for each counter
        if ((holders[0, 1].getValue() == CT1 && holders[1, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, 3].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, 4].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[0, 1].getValue() == CT2 && holders[1, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, 3].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, 4].getValue() == CT2))
        {
            isWon = true;
        }

//Diagonal from [0, 3] to [3, 0] for each counter
        else if ((holders[0, 3].getValue() == CT1 && holders[1, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, 1].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, 0].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[0, 3].getValue() == CT2 && holders[1, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, 1].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, 0].getValue() == CT2))
        {
            isWon = true;
        }
        //Diagonal from [0, 4] to [3, 1] for each counter     
        else if ((holders[0, 4].getValue() == CT1 && holders[1, 3].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, 1].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[0, 4].getValue() == CT2 && holders[1, 3].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, 1].getValue() == CT2))
        {
            isWon = true;
        }
        //Diagonal from [1,0] to [4,3] for each counter
        if ((holders[1, 0].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, 1].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[4, 3].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[1, 0].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, 1].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[4, 3].getValue() == CT2))
        {
            isWon = true;
        }
        //Diagonal from [1,1] to [4,4] for each counter
        else if ((holders[1, 1].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, 3].getValue() == CT1 && holders[4, 4].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[1, 1].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, 3].getValue() == CT2 && holders[4, 4].getValue() == CT2))
        {
            isWon = true;
        }
        //Diagonal from [1, 3] to [4, 0] for each counter
        else if ((holders[1, 3].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, 1].getValue() == CT1 && holders[4, 0].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[1, 3].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, 1].getValue() == CT2 && holders[4, 0].getValue() == CT2))
        {
            isWon = true;
        }
        //Diagonal from [1, 4] to [4, 1] for each counter     
        else if ((holders[1, 4].getValue() == CT1 && holders[2, 3].getValue() == CT1 && holders[3, 2].getValue() == CT1 && holders[4, 1].getValue() == CT1) || (holders[1, 4].getValue() == CT2 && holders[2, 3].getValue() == CT2 && holders[3, 2].getValue() == CT2 && holders[4, 1].getValue() == CT2))
        {
            isWon = true;
        }
        return isWon;

    }












}

class Holder
{
    private Point location;

    private int value = Board.B;

    public void setLocation(Point p)
    {
        location = p;
    }
    public Point getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int i)
    {
        value = i;
    }




}
```

}

Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: have a look into MVP pattern. should help you

Comment: You could use a bool value for each column. When the column becomes full, set that column's bool value to false. Then when users try to add to that column check the bool value and act accordingly.

Comment: Ok will do @user853710 and thanks ProgrammingDude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't update your movesMade variable unless the move is a valid one. I would encapsulate the validation of the move itself as a separate bit of game logic and only update movesMade if valid. The state of the columns will dictate whether a move is valid or not. A 2 dimensional array with 3 possible values for each element would do fine for a data model. And it'd be trivial to then deduce if each column was full, whether moves were valid, etc.

I'd also simply use a boolean (e.g. playerOneActive) to store whose move it is, in a 2 player game e.g. Player 1 = true, Player 2 = false.

There's also a lot of potential code duplication in your detectHit method, which could be improved through an additional method to handle each scenario of your if-else-if construct.